# How to add other website in Digitalocean?

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean, ghost-blog

I would like to add my portfolio website in Digitalocean, but I can't (the server is running Ubuntu).

In the SSH terminal:

```
$ var/www/ghost/
```

http://firstziiz.com -> this is Ghost blog

---

I push my website folder in /www

```
$ var/www/portfolio/
```

http://firstziiz.com/portfolio -> don't my portfolio but 404 Error T_T

---

What should I do to get this working?

Comment: I mix different tutorials and update them to find the solution. I write an article which combine all the information if you want to serve several Ghost blogs in one droplet. [Install multiple Ghost CMS on DigitalOcean](https://medium.com/pixel-for-creative-people/install-multi-ghost-cms-on-digitalocean-85f7c73ed782)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you serving the Ghost blog? The most common method is to use an Nginx reverse proxy. Assuming that what you are doing, you should be able to serve a static website by using [an alias directive.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) Your Nginx configuration should look something like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name firstziiz.com;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 10G;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

    location /portfolio/ {
        alias /var/www/portfolio/;
    }

}
```